# Change the Source DB for migrating via Drush

Tags: 8, migrations

A few days ago I originally ran the full migration via the UI to get the site up and running and cleaning up any bugs from a DB instance that is a copy of the current live site. However, now that the site is up and running, I would like to re-migrate just the users from a NEW copy of the current live site in order to have an up-to-date data before going live (instead of losing any changes users made over the last few days).

- I don't want to re-migrate through the UI because I just need to migrate users
- I tried adding a `$databases['migrate']['default']` setting in the `settings.php` file but `migrate-import` doesn't have any option like `--legacy-db-key`
- `drush migrate-status` gives me an error because I deleted the backup db after I successfully migrated, but can't figure out a way to change the source DB

How can I change the source DB for the `migrate` drush commands in order to run a migration on just users via the `drush migrate-import` command?

Answer (score 0):

in settings.php add the connection to the source database (that contains users you want to migrate)

```
$databases['myuserssourcedb']['default'] = [
  'database' => '',
  'username' => '',
  'password' => '',
  'host' => '',
  'port' => '',
  'driver' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'collation' => '',
];
```

in your migration yml file reference the source database as 'key' in the 'source'

```
id: migration_of_users
label: 'Migrate users from old database'
migration_group: migration
source:
  plugin: mypluginforusers
  key: myuserssourcedb  <-----This is the important line
process:
```